# Websphere hung thread - monitor lock on WASJSPExtensionServletWrapper

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, websphere, richfaces

All,

I am receiving intermittent hung threads in Websphere 8.5.5.5 in a JSF 2.0 application:

```
Thread Name
WebContainer : 8
State
Waiting on condition
Monitor
Owns Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/ws/WASJSPExtensionServletWrapper@0x0000000109FF9FE0
Java Stack
at java/lang/Thread.sleep(Native Method) 
at java/lang/Thread.sleep(Thread.java:904(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.doDestroy(ServletWrapper.java:1019(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapperImpl.doDestroy(ServletWrapperImpl.java:337(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/servlet/ServletWrapper.prepareForReload(ServletWrapper.java:1112(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/wsspi/webcontainer/servlet/GenericServletWrapper.prepareForReload(GenericServletWrapper.java:132(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:529(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:294(Compiled Code)) 
at com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:163(Compiled Code))
```

This `WebContainer #8` thread was blocking roughly 72 other WebContainer threads due to contention over its 1 monitor lock. This was locking the shared object `WASJSPExtensionServletWrapper`.

I am assuming due to location of error above that this is occurring during a JSP tag translation, maybe during a slow-running custom tag or Rich Faces 4.3.2 tag (AJAX call a4j) that causes the Servlet to reload slowly and hang due to a context switch?

In a custom tag I had occasional TreeMap errors due to a deprecated call to VariableResolver which I subsequently changed to ELResolver.  And in the Rich Faces AJAX calls I see this unsynchronized code:

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
data.put("customerSum", collectedBalance);
```

followed by this code which does a get:

```
JSONObject dataToJSON = new JSONObject()
dataToJSON.put("customerSum", data.get("customerSum"));
```

However, I am having a terrible time to either:
(1) prove via hard evidence the smoking gun is `TreeMap.put` or `HashMap.put` or get?
(2) reproduce the issue?

What could cause a Servlet to reload right after a JSP tag _checkForTranslation? Could this be a reload due to running into an error or NullPointerException or an infinite loop? I don't see anything clearly in the SystemOut.log.

Since I changed to ElResolver and removed the AJAX calls with that HashMap, I haven't seen this issue. Yet, I need to be able to prove the root cause?  (I also wouldn't mind being able to put back the AJAX calls?)  I also am uncertain whether this may just be due to a high number of requests (due to number of AJAX calls?) rather than due to a slow-running custom tag? But traffic is modest.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated . . . Thank you.

PS I know that Rich Faces is end-of-life, but replacing it will take time, in a future project maybe . . .

UPDATE 8/3/2016: Today we noticed that the JSP page .class files in Production server are continuously being re-compiled and reloaded. This is not necessary and should NOT be the case. Investigating whether this may be setting up the conditions which lead to the intermittent hung thread upon destroying/reloading the JSP page servlet.

Answer (score 0):

As for the JSPs being recompiled on each request, you should look in to APAR PI12939 to see if applies to your environment.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI12939

If the JSPs were initially compile using one user and the server is running in another then the JSP Container could be having a hard time updating the timestamp of the .class file...therefore resulting in it thinking the JSP is out of date on each request and attempting a re-translation and re-compile.  There is a JSP attribute that can be set to alleviate this scenario:

To enable this behavior the following JSP attribute must be
set to "true":
deleteClassFilesBeforeRecompile

set that JSP attribute in your application's ibm-web-ext.xml file.  Please note that if you are updating an app that is already installed then update the version of the ibm-web-ext.xml file that is nested in the profile's config directory and not the installedApps directory.

Another option is to set the reloadEnabled JSP attribute to false.  This would prevent the JSP Container from continuously checking to see if the JSP needs to be recompiled.  This, however, is just masking what the real issue would be.